# How does combining these two methods return the value 5?

Tags: ruby

```
def add_one(number)
  number + 1
end

puts add_one(5)

def add_two(number)
  number = add_one(number)
  add_one(number)
end

puts add_two(3)
```

Hello. I completely understand the first method. However, I am now trying to understand combining methods as we can see from method add_two. I am clueless to how the second method can return 5?

From my knowledge, we call the method add_two and pass the number '3' into the argument. From there we get one local variable number with the object 3. From there I do not understand how we can include the add_one method when we haven't defined it below? Can someone walk me through the second method?

Let me help you understand my logic by breaking the components down below:

```
first method: 

    add_one(5)
    5 + 1 = 6

second method:

   add_two(3)
   3 = number + 1
   number + 1
```

Am I right by thinking of the second method like this above?

Comment: since `add_one` is defined first, it can be used inside `add_two`

Comment: No I understand the method has been defined first so we can include it in the second method. But how is this producing the value '5' in the last method? I don't understand this.

Comment: Why not just print back every single line and figure out why and what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `add_two` method, the line `number = add_one(number)` overrides the value in `number` with the result of `add_one(number)`:

For example, when you call `add_two(3)`, this happens:

```
number = add_one(number)
number = add_one(3)
number = 4
```

On the second line you call `add_one` again, but with the modified `number`, that is, it no longer has value `3` it is now `4`, as it was overwritten in previous line.

So second line `add_one(number)` becomes `add_one(4)`, thus the result is `5`.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. However, I still don't quite understand why we have to assign add_one(number) to the variable 'number' on line two? Because below that line we can just call 'add_one(number)' and it works by adding +1 without assigning it to the same variable.

Comment: @Benjamints what are you trying to accomplish with `add_two` method? You don't need to `add_one(number)` to any variable unless you plan to use that variable later. For example, if you don't assign the `add_one(number)` to `number`, then you will never change its value and the result of will be `4` instead of `5`.

Answer (score 0):

your interpretation of the second function is incorrect.

```
second method:

  add_two(number(3))
  number = number(3) + 1 #=> 4
  number(4) + 1          #=> 5
```

the first line in the second function is processed as `add_one(number) store result at number` so number after that line is now 4 not 3

the second line is processed as `add_one(number) and return result` which is 5